# Find and display in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with columns below

[image]

now what I am trying to achieve is as below.

1. for one particular WIRE how many distinct MODULES are present and list them.
2. Now we have list of distinct MODULES---search for WIRE which has same MODULE list we found in first step.
3. All MODULES found should have similar content of COMBO1
4. Now need to do this for all wires and then list like below

[image]

table structure is like this

[image]

output expected as below
Wire  module

```
Abc   1023828
Xyz   1209812
Lmn   7675675
Pqr   3453645
      7687687
      7678778
      7897967

wre   240928
aak   349080
      092300
      209380
```

Comment: Add table structure, sample data and desired output in text format. Otherwise this question may get closed

Comment: But `WIRE` is different for every row, and some rows are blank?

Comment: you are looking at the output....I need output like that...is it possible?

Comment: So the first column has blanks? Or the previous value is repeated?

Comment: original table I have on which I am trying to perform operations is does not have blanks.
it has all the fields. both columns WIRE and MODULE contains repeated values.

Comment: The original table I have on which I am trying to perform operations does not have blanks.

The image I have shown here (where you see blank values in WIRE) is what I am looking for as a final result.

NOTE: Orignal table has all the fields occupied. but in both columns, WIRE and MODULE contains repeated values(just to let you know)